# How to set the edge's length in cytoscape.js with cola?

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, cytoscape.js

I am using the latest version of cytoscape.js and cola.js.
When I change "edgelength" nothing happens.

how can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide some code that you have tried? or any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify one of `edgeLength`, `edgeSymDiffLength`, or `edgeJaccardLength` in the layout options.

From [the docs](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/cola):

```
// different methods of specifying edge length
// each can be a constant numerical value or a function like `function( edge ){ return 2; }`
edgeLength: undefined, // sets edge length directly in simulation
edgeSymDiffLength: undefined, // symmetric diff edge length in simulation
edgeJaccardLength: undefined, // jaccard edge length in simulation
```

As this is a force-directed layout and you can set multiple constraints, you may not get the effect you're looking for if you overconstrain the system -- which is easy to do.  Consider that constraints on some edge lengths may contradict constraints on other edge lengths.